# IdentityServer4 with webforms & multi-tenanted environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

We are a new tech team that has inherited a webforms app. We are planning on building out an internal API and would like some guidance for implementing it with our existing app.

Ideally we would like an independent app hosting the identity server, and both internal APIs and webform app would call it. However, we host hundreds of websites on a single platform in a multi-tenanted setup.

- Can we use IS4 with webforms?
- Can you give some guidance around multi-tenanted setups?
- Can we use cookie based authentication in the webforms app and use the same token for delegated access when communicating with the api?
- Have I missed anything obvious?

Comment: What do you use to store your users?

Comment: Currently just a SQL dB, each client has their own dB.

Comment: Are you looking to use IdentityServer4 2.x with .Net Core 2.x or IdentityServer1.x with .Net Core 1.x?

Comment: Ideally I would use the most recent version of IdentityServer (self-hosted in .NET Core) - but are the client libraries compatible with WebForms (running .NET 4.6.2)

Comment: You will setup the IdentityServer4 as a separate web App/api that will be .Net Core and your other applications will use the api. I found some documentation that I’ll post later tonight.

Comment: @aaronR Would you mind sharing the documentation you're talking about? I'm interested in the same question.

Comment: @JohnH My answer here has some links that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326701/identityserver4-legacy-net-webforms-application/48328649#48328649

Comment: Webforms do work as I have got them working myself but they won't have the /signout-oidc endpoint for front channel sighn out - you need to implament that yourself - how to do this i'm still looking it up