# IdentityServer4 + Legacy .Net WebForms Application

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

We have a legacy .net 4.5.2 WebForms application that uses an old customized version of IdentityServer2 for auth. We have an opportunity to replace it right now, but all the setup examples I see for IdentityServer4 assume an MVC application.

Does IdentityServer4 support WebForms applications out of the box? I'm not interested in turning this application into anymore of a Frankenstein.

Comment: "IdentityServer is a free, open source OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for ASP.NET Core." from their github page, https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically any oidc provider will do for the client, in order to communicate with IdentityServer4. The question is not if IdentityServer4 supports web applications, but if you can find client side code to communicate with IdentityServer4.

For 4.5.2 applications you can use *IdentityServer3* NuGet packages. Please read this [article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4). Can it be used for webforms? Yes, according to [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/78) question. There is also a [webforms sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/WebFormsClient) available.