# Is it possible to add ASP.NET Core Identity to a WebForms project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I know it is possible [to add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project) ASP.NET Identity (note NOT Core) to a WebForms project. But what I want to do is add [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to an existing WebForms project.

1. Is this possible?
2. If 1. is not possible, then how do I share an ASP.NET Core Identity user database between my .NET Core application and WebForms application so that I can implement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-a-common-user-database

Comment: In this case, I would take a look at using Identity Server.

Comment: @penleychan yeah considering that - just trying to find an end to end example as there are bits and pieces https://stackoverflow.com/a/48328649/223742 but not a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to share the database

**Option 1**: you will need to do some custom implementation since Core Identity (v3) might have a slightly different schema than .NET Framework Identity (v2). Take a look at the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/index

You might need to also override the PasswordHasher if they are different implementations. Check the following article out: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-asp-net-core-identity-passwordhasher/

**Option 2**: You can expose login/registering/membership functionality from your Core project and consume from your WebForm as a rest service. There are several rest security schemes and middleware.

See:

- https://garywoodfine.com/asp-net-core-2-2-jwt-authentication-tutorial/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/

Those are a few quick ones. You can probably extrapolate and get some other ideas from looking at the source for Identity lib (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Identity) If you scroll down the readme you'll see different Store providers. For **Option 1** you would need to essentially write a Core Store for your Web Forms Identity lib (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=aspnetwebstack)

Comment: First link is down :(

Comment: Hey @Marin updated the link above to a working article and here is a third one in case just in case: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api