# Login with Identity Provider using IdentityServer and Authenticate Users via OpenID

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, identityserver3

I am new to IdentityServer concepts and require help in how we authenticate users. I have a web form project where I changed default Authentication to Individual User Account. Have registered some users, and successfully able to create claims and authenticate. Now I want to implement SSO with OpenID authentication, so I added IdentityServer3 to my project and made following changes in Start.Auth.cs file, under **ConfigAuth** method.

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            Authority = "http://localhost:52262/Core",
            ClientId = "webforms.owin.implicit",
            RedirectUri = "~/Default.aspx",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "~/Login.aspx",
            ResponseType = "id_token token",
            Scope = "openid profile email",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                  {
                      //var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                      //var sub = id.FindFirst(IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject);
                      //var roles = id.FindAll(IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                      //// create new identity and set name and role claim type
                      //var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                      //        id.AuthenticationType,
                      //        IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Name
                      //        , IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Role
                      //        );

                      //nid.AddClaim(sub);
                      //nid.AddClaims(roles);
                      //// keep the id_token for logout
                      //nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                      //n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                      //    nid,
                      //    n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

                      //return Task.FromResult(0);


                      var claims_to_exclude = new[]
                      {
                              "aud", "iss", "nbf", "exp", "nonce", "iat", "at_hash"
                            };

                      var claims_to_keep =
                          n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims
                          .Where(x => false == claims_to_exclude.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();
                      claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                      if (n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken != null)
                      {
                          claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                          var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(new Uri("http://localhost:52262/core/connect/userinfo"), n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);
                          var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();
                          var userInfoClaims = userInfoResponse.Claims
                              .Where(x => x.Item1 != "sub") // filter sub since we're already getting it from id_token
                              .Select(x => new Claim(x.Item1, x.Item2));
                          claims_to_keep.AddRange(userInfoClaims);
                      }

                      var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(
                          n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
                          "name", "role");
                      ci.AddClaims(claims_to_keep);

                      n.AuthenticationTicket = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket(
                          ci, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties
                      );
                  },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                    {
                        var id_token = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token")?.Value;
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = id_token;
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });

        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

I have also added some Claims Transformation logic as well which gets called from Login.aspx.cs file, if user is able to successfully login (SignInStatus.Success:).

```
public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
        if (!incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return base.Authenticate(resourceName, incomingPrincipal);
        }            
        var newPrincipal = CreateApplicationPrincipal(incomingPrincipal.Identity.Name, incomingPrincipal.Identity.GetUserId());

        EstablishSession(newPrincipal);

        return newPrincipal;
    }

    private void EstablishSession(ClaimsPrincipal newPrincipal)
    {
        var sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken(newPrincipal, TimeSpan.FromHours(8))
        {
            IsPersistent = false, // make persistent
            IsReferenceMode = true // cache on server
        };

        FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);
    }

    private ClaimsPrincipal CreateApplicationPrincipal(string name, string v)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        if(name == "sid@test.com")
        {
            var p = Principal.Create("Application",
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Sidd"));               

            var manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();                

            var manager1 = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();

            var user = manager.FindByName(name);

            manager.GetRoles(user.Id).ToList().ForEach(
                role => p.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

            return p;
        }
        else
        {
            return Principal.Create("Application",
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name),
               new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, name));
        }

        //return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "form"));
    }
```

Now my question is:

1.) How to validate against my member database using OpenID connect with IdentityServer3

2.) Achieve SSO or test for SSO after I redirect back to my Default.aspx.cs page from a winform app or any other domain or request page

3.) What url value should come under Authority for open id

4.) Do we need to add any certificates, if so how?.

5.) I currently have a sql server database. How can re-use the User table and authenticate (if not via ASP.NET Identity manager).

Any help or links or suggestions would be great. I am struggling a lot to get this code right, and would be good if I get some headway with the code logic.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Comment: Please be aware that IdentityServer3 is currently [unsupported](https://leastprivilege.com/2019/07/03/end-of-identityserver3-free-support/).

Comment: So will IdentityServer4 work with asp.net web forms or MVC 5. I guess it works only with .net core?.

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326701/identityserver4-legacy-net-webforms-application/48328649#48328649): IdentityServer4 + Legacy .Net WebForms Application.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You have to implement IUserService and inject it in the IoC. That implementation should dip into your user store and make sure the credentials and whatnot is valid and set the appropriate AuthenticateResult on the context.

2.) Once step 1 is done, you will have a session cookie on the IdSrv that will ensure SSO with other clients who use the same provider.

3.) authority is the root uri where your IdSrv is hosted. Looks like its http://localhost:52262/Core for you, but check your Startup for IdSrv.

4.) There should be a signing pfx certificate provided with the demos, but you can (and should eventually) also generate your own.

5.) See #1

[Here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/CustomUserService/CustomUserService/LocalRegistrationUserService.cs) is a boiler-plate IUserService implementation, but as mentioned, yours should go into the database and verify the user.